# Computer won’t turn on

Tags: power-supply

I woke up this morning and my computer won’t switch on. I have tried to do the screwdriver trick with the front panel connectors but even that won’t work. Any answers will be appreciated.

Specs:

- AMD A4 6300 APU with Radeon HD Graphics
- Gigabyte GA-F2A55M
- Corsair CX600
- Western Digital 1TB Hard Drive
- NZXT Source 210
- Corsair Vengeance 4GB RAM Stick

Comment: I would try plugging a desk lamp into the socket your computer is hooked up to to ensure you do not have a blown fuse / circuit breaker first.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have already done that and has ensured that the power socket is running fine.

Comment: bad weather ? lightning in the area ?

Comment: Nope, we very rarely get lightning in England.

Answer (score 2):

Check the back of the PSU for a second power switch.

Check wiring.  Make sure no cables to motherborad got unplugged.

I've had a situation where the switch on the back of the PSU was set to off.  So I tried to flip it on, but the switch would immediately (physically) flip back off.  So I bought a new PSU; when replacing the PSU I noticed the old one bulged. It was a physically bad PSU. I learned my lesson about buying cheap PSUs.

Moral of story: if all cabling seems fine, try replacing parts.  Even if you don't have a bad part, that may be informative as you find out what does cause things to start working.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I don't have a second power switch. I really didn't think that I would have to resort to replacing parts but it looks like that is the way I would have to go. Is the Corsair CX600 cheap though?

Comment: Corsair has its fans for reliability.  The PSU I had which was quite bad was a different brand.  If your system isn't spinning fans when you try to turn it on, I tend to lean towards blaming the PSU, the motherboard (less likely), or a cable (perhaps the Mobo is lacking power).  Sometimes there is the main set of cables that the motherboard needs, and another smaller amount of cabling going to another spot on the motherboard.

Comment: Thank you, it looks that I have to replace the PSU because the max power my computer needed was 430w and I chose to go with 600w because of upgradability.Which PSU do you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have checked the outlet it working, first confirm whether the power supply is on.  If you have a PSU tester on hand, you can test to see if the PSU is at fault.

Next is to try removing components and see if that will let the computer POST.

Starting from easiest to hardest:

- HDD/SSD (just unplug them)
- Video card
- RAM

If the computer does not POST with just the CPU (multiple beeps if there is no RAM/video card), then changing PSU is the cheapest test.  Next will be mobo/CPU.

Can't think of anything else to do and it won't be a software issue since it isn't even turning on.